# How to make C# Com object GlobalMultiUse?

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop, atl

I am doing some COM interop (VBA client) and there is a feature that perhaps I have taken for granted, a global ready-instantiated object is available if in the idl you use the idl attribute `appobject`.  This works in ATL/C++ so I can write the following IDL (ATL project)

```
[
    uuid(183343ca-6154-4c1e-9a6b-927e5b279332),
    version(1.0),
]
library GlobalCOMObjectLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        odl,
        uuid(f1bd66ae-4fc9-45a4-8a2b-60df31d9bcfe),
        version(1.0),
        dual,
        oleautomation
    ]
    interface ISampleGlobalObject : IDispatch
    {
        HRESULT Line([in]BSTR sIn, [out, retval] BSTR* outRetVal);
    };

    [
        uuid(6a905a18-37d2-4ac1-a663-871f7dc99af7),
        version(1.0),
        appobject 
    ]
    coclass SampleGlobalObject
    {
        [default] interface ISampleGlobalObject;
    };
};
```

and then in the VBA I do not need to New the coclass I can write the following

```
Sub TestGlobal3()
    Debug.Print SampleGlobalObject.Line("hello")
End Sub
```

How does one do the same in C#, `appobject` as an attribute is not recognized (squiggly line)

```
namespace foo
{
    public interface ISampleGlobalObjectCSharp
    {
        string Line(string sLine);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ISampleGlobalObjectCSharp))]
    [appobject]
    public class SampleGlobalObject : ISampleGlobalObjectCSharp
    {
        string ISampleGlobalObjectCSharp.Line(string sLine)
        {
            return sLine;
        }
    }
```

Googling around encounters pages wirtten during era of transition from VB6 to C# and they suggest it is not possible.  The VB6 term is `GlobalMultiUse`, if that triggers any memories.

Comment: Those pages are correct.  Ideally the type library exporter would pay attention to a [TypeLibType] attribute, but it doesn't.  It is not like you can't get it, but it is error-prone and very hard to automate.  Decompile the .tlb file with Oleview.exe, File > View TypeLib, copy/paste the decompiled idl and edit in the [appobject] attribute, rebuild the .tlb with midl.exe /tlb.  The workaround in VBA is much easier.  Fwiw, GlobalMultiUse is something completely different, affects only the REGCLS that an out-of-process server uses.

Comment: @HansPassant : yep that worked.  Cheers Hans.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a comment to an answer to preserve it:

> Those pages are correct. Ideally the type library exporter would pay
> attention to a [TypeLibType] attribute, but it doesn't. It is not like
> you can't get it, but it is error-prone and very hard to automate.
> Decompile the .tlb file with Oleview.exe, File > View TypeLib,
> copy/paste the decompiled idl and edit in the [appobject] attribute,
> rebuild the .tlb with midl.exe /tlb. The workaround in VBA is much
> easier. Fwiw, GlobalMultiUse is something completely different,
> affects only the REGCLS that an out-of-process server uses.

– Hans Passant May 4 '18 at 13:05

---

This comment was stated by the OP to be correct.